# Issue with styling the text within a css shaped links

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-shapes

I have created a step / pointer horizontal navigation by creating shapes in CSS. The issue I am having is I cant seem to position and style the text "*Step X: Some text*" within the links. I have a span class around the link text that i want to position and style inside, however it doesnt seem to do anything to the text, but does to the overall link. For example if i style the text as margin-top: 25px; the text doesnt move but the whole navigation bar does.

Can someone please correct this issue and tell me how it suppose to be done, it would be very much appreciated!

**This is my html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="shappednav.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navh">
            <ul >
                <li id="item1"><a href="#" <span class="text">Step 1: Some text</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" <span class="text">Step 2: Some text</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" <span class="text">Step 3: Some text</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" <span class="text">Step 4: Some text</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is my CSS:**

```
.navh{
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em auto;
    clear: both;
    border-bottom: none;  
}

.navh ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navh li a  {
    width: 180px;
    height: 125px;
    position: relative;
    background: #1b9fa4;
    border-radius:2%;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #e91e63 ;
    border-color: #1b9fa4;
}

#item1 :after {
   border-left: 0px solid; 
}

.navh li  :after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 62.5px solid white;
    border-top: 62.5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 62.5px solid transparent;
    z-index:1;
}

.navh li :before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -62.5px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 62.5px solid #e91e63;
    border-top: 62.5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 62.5px solid transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}

.navh li a:hover{
    background: yellow;
}

.navh li a:hover:before {
    border-left: 62.5px solid yellow;
/*  border-top: 62.5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 62.5px solid transparent;*/
}

span.text {
    border:solid;
    Color:white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I have tried your code as well and nothing happens :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all you got to do is set the css to:

```
.text {
border:solid;
Color:white;

}
```

```css
.navh{
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em auto;
    clear: both;
    border-bottom: none;  
 
}

.navh ul{
list-style-type: none;

}


.navh li a  {
  width: 180px;
  height: 125px;
  position: relative;
  background: #1b9fa4;
  border-radius:2%;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #e91e63 ;
  border-color: #1b9fa4;
  

}


#item1 :after {
       border-left: 0px solid; 
  }

  .navh li  :after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 62.5px solid white;
  border-top: 62.5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 62.5px solid transparent;
  z-index:1;

}
.navh li :before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -62.5px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 62.5px solid #e91e63;
    border-top: 62.5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 62.5px solid transparent;
    z-index: 2;

}
.navh li a:hover{
background: yellow;
}


.navh li a:hover:before {
    border-left: 62.5px solid yellow;
/*    border-top: 62.5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 62.5px solid transparent;*/
}



.text {

}

a {
Color:white;
text-align: right;
line-height: 115px;   

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="shappednav.css">
      
  </head>

  <body>


<div class="navh">
  <ul >
    <li id="item1"><a href="#"> <span class="text">Step 1: Some text</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <span class="text">Step 2: Some text</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <span class="text">Step 3: Some text</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <span class="text">Step 4: Some text</span></a></li>
  </ul>

 </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I have tried that and ran your code, it doesnt move the text, it move the whole navigation bar 25px from the top

Comment: ic..you want the css code to move the text...one sec ill update my answer

Comment: let me know how that looks for you:)

Comment: Thanks for trying again, appreciate it.  I can see you got the text moving, but i need it in the original shape it was in, All i need is the text to be styled and positioned in the center of the arrow

Comment: Thanks Blackfox, its getting alot closer, how do  i move it more to the right and wrap it if i need to? Usually we would use margin to position elements - Dont worry if you cant do any more, get some rest and thanks for your help. It just odd how it behaves

Comment: text-align: right; ...made the edit too...please except answer and use the website resource i shared:)

Comment: Thanks again - I have ran the code, the triangle part of the link doesnt turn yellow anymore, but not to worry as you helped enought. Also where do i access the website resource you shared?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.navh li a span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your response and for trying to help, i have tried your code and unfortunately nothing happens :(

Comment: Your HTML structure is messed up. Close the `<a>` tags before opening the `<span>` tags.

Comment: Thanks I have also tried your code, whilst the text is able to move it messes up the whole naviagtion overall